# Drag items between QTreeWidget and QListWidget in PyQt5?

Tags: python, pyqt, drag-and-drop, pyqt5, qtreewidget

I have a QListWidget and a QTreeWidget and I want to be able to drag one or multiple list items around within each one as well as between them. I have the internal drag and drop working, but I'm not sure how to drag between them.

[image]

When I print `event.mimeData().formats()` in my code below it says `['application/x-qabstractitemmodeldatalist']`. I am stuck on how to extract the text and index of that item (it should be a QListWidgetItem or QTreeWidgetItem, right?) so I can delete the original from the source widget and add a new item to the destination widget, how do I do that?

I tried using code from here:
https://wiki.python.org/moin/PyQt/Handling%20Qt%27s%20internal%20item%20MIME%20type

So currently my code gets a QVariant items when I drag items between the widgets, but I still don't know what to do with those to get the item text and index.

```
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtWidgets, QtGui
from PyQt5.QtCore import Qt
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QTreeWidgetItem
import sys

class Tree(QtWidgets.QTreeWidget):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super().__init__(parent)

        self.setDragDropMode(self.DragDrop)
        self.setSelectionMode(self.ExtendedSelection)
        self.setAcceptDrops(True)

        for text in ['tree1','tree2','tree3']:
            treeItem = QtWidgets.QTreeWidgetItem(self, [text])
            treeItem.setFlags(treeItem.flags() & ~QtCore.Qt.ItemIsDropEnabled)
            self.addTopLevelItem(treeItem)

    def dropEvent(self, event):
        if event.source() == self:
            event.setDropAction(QtCore.Qt.MoveAction)
            super().dropEvent(event)
        elif isinstance(event.source(), QtWidgets.QListWidget):
            item = self.itemAt(event.pos())
            ix = self.indexAt(event.pos())
            col = 0 if item is None else ix.column()
            item = self.invisibleRootItem() if item is None else item
            ba = event.mimeData().data('application/x-qabstractitemmodeldatalist')
            data_items = decode_data(ba)
            for data_item in data_items:
                it = QtWidgets.QTreeWidgetItem()
                item.addChild(it)
                for data in data_items:
                    for r, v in data.items():
                        it.setData(col, r, v)


class List(QtWidgets.QListWidget):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super().__init__(parent)

        self.setDragDropMode(self.DragDrop)
        self.setSelectionMode(self.ExtendedSelection)
        self.setAcceptDrops(True)

        for text in ['list1','list2','list3']:
            self.addItem(text)

    def dropEvent(self, event):
        if event.source() == self:
            event.setDropAction(QtCore.Qt.MoveAction)
            QtWidgets.QListWidget.dropEvent(self, event)
        elif isinstance(event.source(), QtWidgets.QTreeWidget):
            item = self.itemAt(event.pos())
            row = self.row(item) if item else self.count()
            ba = event.mimeData().data('application/x-qabstractitemmodeldatalist')
            data_items = decode_data(ba)
            for i, data_item in enumerate(data_items):
                it = QtWidgets.QListWidgetItem()
                self.insertItem(row+i, it)
                for r, v in data_item.items():
                    it.setData(r,v)


def decode_data(bytearray):

    data = []
    item = {}

    ds = QtCore.QDataStream(bytearray)
    while not ds.atEnd():

        row = ds.readInt32()
        column = ds.readInt32()

        map_items = ds.readInt32()
        for i in range(map_items):
            key = ds.readInt32()

            value = QtCore.QVariant()
            ds >> value
            item[Qt.ItemDataRole(key)] = value

        data.append(item)
    return data

if __name__=='__main__':

    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)

    layout = QtWidgets.QHBoxLayout()
    layout.addWidget(Tree())
    layout.addWidget(List())

    container = QtWidgets.QWidget()
    container.setLayout(layout)
    container.show()

    app.exec_()
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to create the items using the information returned by decode_data which are the roles and values of each item dragged:

```
class Tree(QtWidgets.QTreeWidget):
    # ...

    def dropEvent(self, event):
        if event.source() == self:
            event.setDropAction(QtCore.Qt.MoveAction)
            super().dropEvent(event)
        elif isinstance(event.source(), QtWidgets.QListWidget):
            item = self.itemAt(event.pos())
            ix = self.indexAt(event.pos())
            col = 0 if item is None else ix.column()
            item = self.invisibleRootItem() if item is None else item            
            ba = event.mimeData().data('application/x-qabstractitemmodeldatalist')
            data_items = decode_data(ba)
            for data_item in data_items:
                it = QtWidgets.QTreeWidgetItem()
                item.addChild(it)
                for data in data_items:
                    for r, v in data.items():
                        it.setData(col, r, v)

class List(QtWidgets.QListWidget):
    # ... 

    def dropEvent(self, event):
        if event.source() == self:
            event.setDropAction(QtCore.Qt.MoveAction)
            QtWidgets.QListWidget.dropEvent(self, event)
        elif isinstance(event.source(), QtWidgets.QTreeWidget):
            item = self.itemAt(event.pos())
            row = self.row(item) if item else self.count()
            ba = event.mimeData().data('application/x-qabstractitemmodeldatalist')
            data_items = decode_data(ba)
            for i, data_item in enumerate(data_items):
                it = QtWidgets.QListWidgetItem()
                self.insertItem(row+i, it)
                for r, v in data_item.items():
                    it.setData(r,v)
```

Comment: I still am confused about the data returned to data_items. When I try to do `qv=data_items[0][Qt.DisplayRole]` then `qv.toString()` I get `AttributeError: 'QVariant' object has no attribute 'toString'`. Shouldn't that work? `type(qv)` is `PyQt5.QtCore.QVariant` and `qv.type()` returns 10 which should be a QString according to this: http://pyqt.sourceforge.net/Docs/PyQt4/qmetatype.html#Type-enum

Comment: PyQt4 Is different to PyQt5

Comment: Oh ok, I usually read the PyQt4 since most PyQt5 sourceforge docs just link to the C++ docs, but it looks like there actually is a page on QVariant. Thanks again